# how to declare global variable in SQL Server..?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use same value for different queries from different DB

like

```
DECLARE @GLOBAL_VAR_1 INT = Value_1

DECLARE @GLOBAL_VAR_2 INT = Value_2

USE "DB_1"
GO
SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = @GLOBAL_VAR_1 

AND "COL_2" = @GLOBAL_VAR_2

USE "DB_2"
GO

SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = @GLOBAL_VAR_2
```

but its giving error.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@GLOBAL_VAR_2".

Can any one suggest any way to do it...?

Comment: Check if this link helps. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/23/60185.aspx

Comment: How "Global" are you looking for? Usable across batches is obvious from your sample script, but should the values be visible/modifiable for other connections?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no way to declare a global variable in Transact-SQL. However, if all you want your variables for is to be accessible across batches of a single script, you can use the **SQLCMD** tool or the **SQLCMD mode** of SSMS and define that tool/mode-specific variables like this:

```
:setvar myvar 10
```

and then use them like this:

```
$(myvar)
```

To use SSMS's SQLCMD mode:

[image]

Comment: @TomTom It is relevant in that it allows you to declare a variable that spans batches.

Comment: @TomTom I do care about question, and looks like you don't. For sqlcmd mode it doesn't matter if it is used in sqlcmd command tool or visual UI. I provided a solution, while minus vote means "answer is not useful". And yes, I insist you are rude.

Comment: @TomTom I'll try last time. Idea of StackOverflow not to answer "No, its' not possible", but to show a way how it can be done. It doesn't matter what 'exactly' asked - people don't know answers to questions they ask, so they need ideas around. It's strange that you behave so having 30k.

Comment: @Lanorkin, what are the implications of using `SQLCMD` mode?

Comment: @craig, it's a separate big question, but in general - `SQLCMD` is `SQL` and `CMD`, so having enough permissions you can do anything inside OS - which might be desired behavior or something you would like to avoid

Comment: This is workable but the better answer for the given example is probably to remove the GO statements so the statements run in a single batch. A lot of people seem to think GO is required after a USE statement, but it is not.

Comment: @Nathan GO is needed for Setting IDENTITY_INSERT

Comment: @Sarfaraaz GO is *not* required for setting IDENTITY_INSERT. GO is a batch terminator and there's nothing in the question code that indicates any need to split the queries up into batches using GO. See the answer from Saini below for the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Too bad @TomTom deleted their comments, I'm curious how they commented on this answer

Answer (score 21):

You **cannot** declare global variables in SQLServer.

If you're using Management Studio you can use SQLCMD mode like @Lanorkin pointed out.

Otherwise you can use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) to store a single variable that is visible during a session and connection, but it'll disappear after that.

Only truly global would be to create a global temp table (named ##yourTableName), and store your variables there, but that will also disappear when all connection are closed.

Comment: Actually I think regarding the multiple queries a normal temp table may also work (not a global one). THe idea with a temp table is neat... as good as it gets within the parameters defined.

Comment: if ##yourTableName is created when the database is created in the db script then it will persist (and have minimal logging)

Answer (score 13):

You could try a global table:

```
create table ##global_var
            (var1 int
            ,var2 int)

USE "DB_1"
GO
SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = (select var1 from ##global_var) 

AND "COL_2" = @GLOBAL_VAR_2

USE "DB_2"
GO

SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = (select var2 from ##global_var)
```

Comment: Is there downsides to using a global table to keep track of variables?

Answer (score 12):

Starting from `SQL Server 2016` a new way for sharing information in session is introduced via the [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql) and [sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql).

You can use them as alternative of `CONTEXT_INFO()` which persist only a binary value limited to 128 bytes. Also, the user can rewrite the value anytime and it's not very good to use it for security checks.

The following issues are resolved using the new utils. You can store the data in more user-friendly format:

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context 'language', 'English';  
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'language');
```

Also, we can mark it as `read-only`:

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context 'user_id', 4, @read_only = 1;
```

If you try to modify a `read-only` session context you will get something like this:

> Msg 15664, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_set_session_context, Line
>   10 Cannot set key 'user_id' in the session context. The key has been set as
>   read_only for this session.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a similar result by creating scalar-valued functions that return the variable values. Of course, function calls can be expensive if you use them in queries that return a large number of results, but if you're limiting the result-set you should be fine. Here I'm using a database created just to hold these semi-static values, but you can create them on a per-database basis, too. As you can see, there are no input variables, just a well-named function that returns a static value: if you change that value in the function, it will instantly change anywhere it's used (the next time it's called).

```
USE [globalDatabase]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.global_GetStandardFonts ()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'font-family:"Calibri Light","sans-serif";'
END
GO

--  Usage: 
SELECT '<html><head><style>body{' + globalDatabase.dbo.global_GetStandardFonts() + '}</style></head><body>...'

--  Result: <html><head><style>body{font-family:"Calibri Light","sans-serif";}</style></head><body>...
```

Comment: You can make this an inline function to avoid the performance hit.

Comment: @ChristopherJ.Grace: thx for pointing that out! Found more info on it here: https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/01/SQL-Server-Scalar-UDF-Inlining

Comment: Until 2019 when they're automatically in-lined. ;)

Comment: @RussellFox so we don't need to worry about inlining functions any more?

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene hypothetically!

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `;` instead of `GO`. It worked for me for 2008 R2 version

```
DECLARE @GLOBAL_VAR_1 INT = Value_1;

DECLARE @GLOBAL_VAR_2 INT = Value_2;

USE "DB_1";
SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = @GLOBAL_VAR_1 

AND "COL_2" = @GLOBAL_VAR_2;

USE "DB_2";

SELECT * FROM "TABLE" WHERE "COL_!" = @GLOBAL_VAR_2;
```

Comment: For the given example, this is the best solution. The GO statement terminates the current batch (and any local variables that had been declared), so as long as you are OK running all the statements in the same batch it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

In that particular example, the error it's because of the GO after the use statements. The GO statements resets the environment, so no user variables exists. They must be declared again. 
And the answer to the global variables question is No, does not exists global variables at least Sql server versions equal or prior to 2008. I cannot assure the same for newer sql server versions.

Regards,
Hini

Answer (score 2):

I like the approach of using a table with a column for each global variable.  This way you get autocomplete to aid in coding the retrieval of the variable.  The table can be restricted to a single row as outlined here: [SQL Server: how to constrain a table to contain a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967372/sql-server-how-to-constrain-a-table-to-contain-a-single-row)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to declare global variables in SQL Server. Sql server has a concept of global variables, but they are system defined and can not be extended.

obviously you can do all kinds of tricks with the SQL you are sending - SqlCOmmand has such a variable replacement mechanism for example - BEFORE you send it to SqlServer, but that is about it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Russell Fox answer, you can create a function to search in a table of global variables:

```
CREATE SCHEMA G -- G for Global
GO
CREATE TABLE G.VAR (
    NAME VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,VALUE VARCHAR(100) )
GO
CREATE PROC G.PSET (@NAME VARCHAR(100), @VALUE VARCHAR(100)) AS BEGIN
         --Insert or update a variable
    MERGE G.VAR T
    USING (SELECT N=@NAME, V=@VALUE) N
        ON NAME = N
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
            SET VALUE = V
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT VALUES (N, V);
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION G.FGET(@NAME VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT TOP 1 VALUE
        FROM G.VAR
        WHERE NAME = @NAME)
END
```

Usage:

```
    --Set new variable or update it
EXEC G.PSET 'name', 'erick de vathaire'
    --Get current value
PRINT 'hi, i am ' + g.fget('name')
```

Answer (score -3):

My first question is which version of SQL Server are you using (i.e 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012)?

Assuming you are using 2008 or later SQL uses scope for variable determination. I believe 2005 still had global variables that would use @@variablename instead of @variable name which would define the difference between global and local variables. Starting in 2008 I believe this was changed to a scope defined variable designation structure. For example to create a global variable the @variable has to be defined at the start of a procedure, function, view, etc. In 2008 and later @@defined system variables for system functions I do believe. I could explain further if you explained the version and also where the variable is being defined, and the error that you are getting.

Comment: 2008 also has global variables. Problem is - you can not define them ;(

Answer (score -4):

```
declare @ID_var int
set @ID_var = 123456

select * from table where ID_var = @ID_var
```

or

```
declare @ID_var varchar(30)
set @ID_var = 123456

select * from table where ID_var = @ID_var
```

Comment: The question is specifically for variables that can be used in multiple separate queries.