# Create global declarations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables

I have multiple stored procedures that use the same declarations and the values  are constant throughout.

Here is a sample of re-used declarations:

```
DECLARE @_status_PO_Auto_Approved as int
DECLARE @_status_PO_Invoice_Exceeds_PO_Amount as int
DECLARE @_status_PO_Item_Code_Mismatch as int

SET @_status_PO_Auto_Approved = 2
SET @_status_PO_Invoice_Exceeds_PO_Amount = 15
SET @_status_PO_Item_Code_Mismatch = 16
```

How can I make these declarations global, so I can use them in different procedures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to declare global variable in SQL Server..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372359/how-to-declare-global-variable-in-sql-server)

Comment: Just set the '@' to '@@' on the start of each variable you want to be global.

Comment: @Zack - not true; not sure why your comment got a +1

Comment: Store them in a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You could do one of a few things though:

- Move them into scalar functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_status_PO_Auto_Approved ...
```

- Write a SQLCMD script to generate those values with a script wide variable.
- My personal preference, create a config table with two (or more) columns, i.e.

```
VariableName                          Value
_status_PO_Auto_Approved              2
_status_PO_Invoice_Exceeds_PO_Amount  15
```

etc.  You could then add constraints and whatnot to ensure that values are unique and/or restricted in whatever ways you need.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are used only in queries, you could also declare them as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo._status_PO
AS
SELECT
  Auto_Approved             = 2,
  Invoice_Exceeds_PO_Amount = 15,
  Item_Code_Mismatch        = 16
;
```

and CROSS JOIN that view in your queries to use the values:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
  CROSS JOIN dbo._status_PO
WHERE
  ... = _status_PO.Auto_Approved
;
```

Comment: This actually looks really interesting, I'll try out.