# Is there any option to set global variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to use some values (table values Ex: StudentId) in many Stored procedures. So I need to query that value in every stored procedure.
In MVC I am able to store that value in WebConfig. But in SQL how can I do that?

Is there any option to store that value globally to refer it in a Stored procedure?

Comment: You can write SP which can return this value ;)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39131/Global-Variables-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1):

If you need configuration values in a database, you can just create a new table and call it something like `ConfigurationParameters`, then query whenever you need a value from it.

If you can't do that, then create a StoredProcedure or Function that always returns the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you can directly make global variables SQL server.

I found another question that is very similar to yours with useful information.

[how to declare global variable in SQL Server..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372359/how-to-declare-global-variable-in-sql-server)

Hope this helps.