# Azure Data Studio use SQL parameters

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-data-studio

Is it possible to use SQL parameter markers by specifying the parameter somewhere in Azure Data Studio?

For example, a query `query.sql` like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ?
```

and having the parameter specified somewhere outside the query when run (for example with pyodbc this would be something like `pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=["param"])`).

Unlike [Azure Data Studio - Setting SQL variables to be used as globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034442/azure-data-studio-setting-sql-variables-to-be-used-as-globals), I don't need a T-SQL global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL parameter markers by fetching the parameters from notebook is possible by using following code:

```
query = "SELECT * from members WHERE Age = ? and Salary < ? "
Age = <value>
Salary = <value>
data_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=(Age,Salary))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is for a python query. I am asking about a SQL query open in Azure Data Studio.

Comment: If it is in SQL, then declare variables and access them in query as mentioned in [this](https://i.imgur.com/b272oRD.png).