# Azure SQL DB - How to create global variables?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need to use a variable in different SPs and functions (say, `@GV_CCY_CD = 'USD'`). How can I declare it globally, then use wherever it is required?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22372569/10549281?

Comment: This sounds like something that belongs in a configuration table. (which would be referenced by all of your SP's and functions)